# Consuming JSON API data with Django

Tags: json, django, api, filtering

From a Django app, I am able to consume data from a separate Restful API, but what about filtering? Below returns all books and its data. But what if I want to grab only books by an author, date, etc.? I want to pass an author's name parameter, e.g. .../*authors-name* or /?author=*name* and return only those in the json response. Is this possible?

*views.py*

```
def get_books(request):
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:8090/book/list/').json()
    return render(request, 'books.html', {'response':response})
```

So is there a way to filter like a model object?

Comment: I don't know anything that comes out-of-the box in Python or Django for that matter, for filtering lists of dictionaries. You could call [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with a predicate function that returns true for a matching book and false otherwise.

Comment: It wouldn't be that hard to build predicates dynamically, so you could write a function with a similar signature to Django's `QuerySet/Manager.filter` that returns custom predicate functions based on keyword arguments.

Comment: I decided to have a go at implementing this.

Comment: Another thought is to make use of the filtering capiblities of the API you're consuming whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways of doing this:

1. Python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) could be used with a bit of additional code.
2. [QueryableList](https://pypi.org/project/QueryableList/), which is the closest to an ORM for lists I've seen.
3. [query-filter](https://pypi.org/project/query-filter/), which takes a more functional approach.

#### 1. Build-in filter function

You can write a function that returns functions that tell you whether a list element is a match and the pass the generated function into `filter`.

```py
def filter_pred_factory(**kwargs):

    def predicate(item):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():

            if key not in item or item[key] != value:
                return False

        return True

    return predicate

def get_books(request):
    books_data = requests.get('http://localhost:8090/book/list/').json()
    pred = filter_pred_factory(**request.GET)
    data_filter = filter(pred, books_data)

    # data_filter is cast to a list as a precaution
    # because it is a filter object,
    # which can only be iterated through once before it's exhausted.
    filtered_data = list(data_filter)
    return render(request, 'books.html', {'books': filtered_data})
```

#### 2. QueryableList

[QueryableList](https://pypi.org/project/QueryableList/) would achieve the same as the above, with some extra features. As well as `/books?isbn=1933988673`, you could use queries like `/books?longDescription__icontains=linux`. You can find other functionality [here](https://github.com/kata198/QueryableList#operations)

```py
from QueryableList import QueryableListDicts

def get_books(request):
    books_data = requests.get('http://localhost:8090/book/list/').json()
    queryable_books = QueryableListDicts(books_data)
    filtered_data = queryable_books.filter(**request.GET)
    return render(request, 'books.html', {'books':filtered_data})
```

#### 3. query-filter

[query-filter](https://pypi.org/project/query-filter/) has similar [features](https://github.com/simoncrowe/python-query-filter#q_s-plural-predicate-keyword-arguemts) but doesn't copy the object-orient approach of an ORM.

```py
from query_filter import q_filter, q_items

def get_books(request):
    books_data = requests.get('http://localhost:8090/book/list/').json()
    data_filter = q_filter(books_data, q_items(**request.GET))

    # filtered_data is cast to a list as a precaution
    # because q_filter returns a filter object, 
    # which can only be iterated through once before it's exhausted.
    filtered_data = list(data_filter)
    return render(request, 'books.html', {'books': filtered_data})
```

It's worth mentioning that I wrote `query-filter`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've been scratching my head over this for more than a week! The particular API takes no params, it's just a list. I did think about dumping the api data into a model but then I thought I was making it more complicated than it should be. I am self taught so it will take me some time to unpack your suggestions but it gives me some direction. I will respond once I've had some time to digest this and do some testing. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: I've found something on GitHub that does what I think you want: https://github.com/kata198/QueryableList

Comment: Here's the PiPy link as well: https://pypi.org/project/QueryableList/

Comment: If it serves your needs I'll update my answer. My filtering idea is not fully developed anyway.

Comment: Hey @Stubb207, hope you had a good holiday (considering world events). I've updated my answer so it's hopefully a lot clearer now. I would appreciate an _accept_ if it properly addresses your question.